# Standard array to tree array

Tags: php

I have a array like this;

[image]

But i want to set array by using level key like this;

[image]

And i am using this code but i know this not a proper solution, so how can you help me ?

```
$array = array(0=>array('tag'=>'one','level'=>1),1=>array('tag'=>'two','level'=>2),2=>array('tag'=>'three','level'=>3));
    foreach($array as $v){

        $level = $v['level'];

        if($level > 0){

            $count[1] = count($tree);
            if($level === 1){
                $tree[$count[1]]['tag'] = $v['tag'];
            }

            if($level > 1){

                $count[2] = (isset($tree[$count[1]-1]['array']))?count($tree[$count[1]-1]['array']):0;
                if($level == 2){
                    $tree[$count[1]-1]['array'][$count[2]]['tag'] = $v['tag'];
                }

                if($level > 2){

                    $count[3] = (isset($tree[$count[1]-1]['array'][$count[2]-1]['array']))?count($tree[$count[1]-1]['array'][$count[2]-1]['array']):0;
                    if($level == 3){
                        $tree[$count[1]-1]['array'][$count[2]-1]['array'][$count[3]]['tag'] = $v['tag'];
                    }

                    if($level > 3){

                        $count[4] = (isset($tree[$count[1]-1]['array'][$count[2]-1]['array'][$count[3]-1]['array']))?count($tree[$count[1]-1]['array'][$count[2]-1]['array'][$count[3]-1]['array']):0;
                        if($level == 4){
                            $tree[$count[1]-1]['array'][$count[2]-1]['array'][$count[3]-1]['array'][$count[4]]['tag'] = $v['tag'];
                        }

                    }

                }



   }

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems to work as you'd want when I run it, https://3v4l.org/cWt9A.

Comment: yes it works but if array have deeper level this code wouldn't work, so i need diffrent type of solution.

Comment: You should ask that than, your first screenshot is not related to the question you just asked.

Answer (score 0):

You made it complex, you can make it like this

```
<?php
  $arrs = [["tag"=>"one","level"=>1],["tag"=>"two","level"=>2],["tag"=>"three","level"=>3]];
  $new = array();
  function setLevel($single){ 
    if($single['level']==1){
      $new["tag"] = $single['tag'];
    }else{
      $single['level'] -= 1;
      $new["array"] = setLevel($single);
    }
    return $new;
  }
  $temp = array();
  foreach($arrs as $key=>$arr){
    $temp = array_merge_recursive($temp,setLevel($arr));
  }
  print_r($temp);
?>
```

Demo 1 : https://eval.in/851578

Demo 2 : https://eval.in/851584

Demo 3 : https://eval.in/851585

Demo 4 : https://eval.in/851586

Answer (score 0):

You can do a recursive function.

```
$tree = setTree($array, 0);

function setTree($v, $i){
    $tree = null;
    $level = $v[$i]['level'];
    if($level > 0){
        $next = $i + 1;
        if(isset($v[$next]))
            $tree = array('0' => array('tag' => $v[$i]['tag'], 'array' => setTree($v, $next)));
        else{
            $tree = array('0' => array('tag' => $v[$i]['tag']));
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

print_r($tree);
```